# How to write extracted data to the outfile. Program is intended to extract email addresses from a file C++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that will extract email addresses from a file and put it into another file. I am don't know how to get the program to put the information in to the other file. Also, do I have to create the second file like I had to create the first one? Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char chr;

int main()
{
string mail;
ifstream inFile;                               //this is the file that we will get the information from
ofstream outfile;                              // this is the file that the data will be saved in 
inFile.open("mail.dat");                     // this will open the file with the original informations
outfile.open("addresses.dat");                // this will open the file where the output will be 
while (inFile)
{
    cin>>mail;
    mail.find('@')!=string::npos;             //this finds the email addresses

}



inFile.close();                               // this will close the file when we are done with it
outfile.close();



cin>>chr;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the extraction should have been done in the expression part of `while ()` loop. Moreover, the part where you "find the email address" is a useless expression. You should be using it as the condition to insert a valid email address into the output file:

```
while (inFile >> mail)
{
    if (mail.find('@') != std::string::npos)
        outFile << mail;
}
```

In your original code, you used `std::cin >> mail`. I was under the impression by your description of the problem that the email address was already stored inside the input file stream. If that *is* the case, you should not be using `std::cin` but rather `inFile` to perform the extraction. I made the correction above.

---

Here's some advice pertaining to the quality of your code. You should not use `using namespace std` in your code. Remove it. It's considered a bad practice. Instead, you should qualify all Standard C++ objects with `std::`.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in;
    std::ifstream out;

    // ...
}
```

Furthermore, both standard file stream objects have a constructor that takes the name of the file. You can still use `open`, but it's more convenient to instantiate from the constructor:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("mail.dat");
    std::ofstream out("addresses.dat");

    // ...
}
```

You should also be using Standard Library algorithms to do trivial things like this. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("mail.dat");
    std::ofstream out("addresses.dat");

    std::remove_copy_if(
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>{in},
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{out, "\n"}, [] (std::string str)
              {
                  return str.find('@') != std::string::npos;
              });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code (from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) shows how to write to file:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Applying this to your situation, you need a line in your loop that writes to the output file. A "file" is really just a different "stream", just like the console. You probably already know how to use `std::cout` - writing to a file is almost exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you expect your program to work, but here's roughly how you would read and write files in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Declare output file variable
    std::ofstream myFile;

    // Open/create text file
    myFile.open("myDocument.txt");

    // Check if it's opened correctly (ie, not in use)
    if(myFile.is_open())
    {
        // Write to the file
        myFile << "Line one.\n";
        myFile << "Line two.\n";
        // Close the file after use
        myFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        // Output an error if we can't open it
        std::cerr << "Could not open file.";
    }

    // Declare input file variable
    std::ifstream readFile;

    // Open this
    readFile.open("myDocument.txt");

    // Check if it opened (ie, not in use)
    if(readFile.is_open())
    {
        // Temp variable to hold read lines
        std::string temp;

        // While not at the end of the document, get the line and store it in temp variable
        while(std::getline(readFile, temp))
        {
            // Output that line to the console
            std::cout << temp << "\n";
        }
        // Close the file
        readFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        // Print an error if we couldn't open the file
        std::cerr << "Could not open file.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses tend to be complex.  Your initial approach to finding all internet email domain addresses will get you plenty, as they are of the form,

```
name@sub.sub.sub.domain.tld
```

Where top level domain (TLD) is a fairly extensive set of values (com, net, edu, gov, us, uk, le, ly, de, so, ru, ...).  Recently IANA announced lifting the restrictions on TLD values, so you will soon have an explosion of new TLD's (apple, ibm, dell, att, cocacola, shell, ...).

The name part can be letters, numbers, and certain special characters.

You might find using a regular expression pattern matching library will help you extract email addresses.

Here are a couple of references that will help,

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address
- http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html
- http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Here are some examples Wikipedia gives of Valid email addresses,

```
niceandsimple@example.com
very.common@example.com
a.little.lengthy.but.fine@dept.example.com
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
user@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]
"much.more unusual"@example.com
"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com
postbox@com (top-level domains are valid hostnames)
!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org
"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
 üñîçøðé@example.com (Unicode characters in local part)
et cetera
```

Once you have extracted one (or several) email addresses from your file, you will want to write each email adress into your outfile.  Assume emaddr contains a valid address,

```
cout<<emaddr<<endl;  //std::cout, std::endl if you don't 'using namespace std'
```

Lest we forget, there are other addressing schemes, you might want to read about,

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.400
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.500

etc.